# Determining if Points Are Parallel.

Tags: calculus

Determine whether the lines l1 and l2 are parallel,
skew, or intersecting. If they intersect, find the point of
intersection.

$l1 : r(t) = (3i + j + 5k) + t(i − j + 2k),$

$l2 : R(u) = (i + 4j + 2k) + u(j + k).$

In order to solve this I first tried to plot out the points. (3,1,5) & (1,-1,2). (1,4,2) & ( 0,1,1). Unfortunately when I plotted them out that is where I lost my direction.I do not understand how to find the point of intersection since this has more than two points and putting into slope intercept form would not derive the right answer in this situation. Would you kindly show me where to go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The lines are not parallel: this would mean the directing vectors $(1,-1,2)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are colinear, which they clearly are not (in the general case, the test is the cross-product of the directing vectors must be $0$).
- they  intersect: the sytem of equations to find an intersection point is:
  $$\begin{cases}
  3+t=1\\1-t=4+u\\5+2t=2+u
  \end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}
  t=-2\\t+u=-3\\2t-u=-3\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}t=-2\\u=-1\end{cases}$$
  (The third equation is compatible with the values found from the first two). Hence the intersection is $\;(1,3,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you need to answer if the two lines are parallel. The lines are paralell if their directional vectors are linearly dependent. In your case, it should be simple to show that $(1,-1,2)$ is not parallel to $(0,1,1)$.

Then, once you showed they are not parallel, they are either skew or they intersect. You can see which by simply trying to find an intersection. If you can, they intersect, if you can prove the intersection does not exist, they are skew.

To find their intersection, think about what an intersection means. An intersection between two lines is a point that is on both lines. Let's call that point $(x_0,y_0, z_0)$. This point lies on $l_1$, so there exists some $t$ such that $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (3,1,5) + t(1,-1,2)$. Also, the point lies on $l_2$, there exists some $u$ that $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,4,2) + u(0,1,1)$.

To find the intersection, you therefore need to find the values of $t,u$ such that $$(3,1,5) + t(1,-1,2) = (1,4,2) + u(0,1,1)$$

This is a system of $3$ equations for $2$ variables, so it may not have a solution.

Comment: I see you have combined l1 and l2 to form a new equation.

Comment: @LittleJon I also explained how the new equation is formed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets convert them in Cartesian.

$l_1: \frac {x-3}{1}=\frac {y-1}{-1}=\frac {z-5}5=t$ &
$l_2: \frac {x-1}0=\frac {y-4}1=\frac {z-2}1 =u$.

From $l_1$ and $l_2$ we get $x=t+3$ and $x=1$ respectively $\Rightarrow t=-2$.
Also, $y=-t+1$ and $y=u+4$ from $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively provide us that $u=-1$.

Hence, Putting values of $t$ and $u$ in their given equations respectively we see that $(1,3,1)$ is the point common point to both the lines.

Hence given lines intersect.